# kustomize not replacing deployed pods

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kustomize

there's probably something i'm not understanding about `kustomize` but using a simple `kustomize edit set image ...` followed by `kustomize build . | kubectl apply -f -` is actually creating duplicate pods rather than replacing pods. It's supposed to be taking my new docker image and replacing the currently deployed pod with a pod that contains the new image. is there some way i can understand why this is happening?

here's my kustomize.yaml. it's very simple. the `images` section is an example result of the `kustomize edit ...` command above

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
- deployment.yaml
- service.yaml
- ingress.yaml
images:
- name: repo.pkg.dev/PROJECT/REPO/IMAGE:TAG
  newName: repo.pkg.dev/.../.../...
  newTag: custom-tag
```

running a simple `kubectl apply` without any of the kustomize stuff used to do exactly what i want before

Comment: Have you checked with a dry-run?

Answer (score 0):

Kustomize doesn't create pods (unless you're deploying a Pod manifest, but those are largely immutable and in any case you're not doing that).

You're updating a Deployment, and the Kubernetes Deployment controller is responsible for creating pods based on the `replicas` and `strategy` settings in your Deployment.

By default, the `strategy.type` field is `RollingUpdate`, which means that when you update the Deployment, Kubernetes will first spin up *new* pods, wait until they become healthy, and then tear down the old pods. During this period you will have "duplicate pods", because that's what you've asked for.

If you want Kubernetes to first tear down existing pods before creating new ones, use the `Replace` strategy instead:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  .
  .
  .
```